# how to target links in a drop down menu when front-end testing

Tags: json, selenium-webdriver

I am venturing into front-end testing. To make this task feel a bit easier I am using selenium builder, but I am struggling to target links on a drop down menu and on a rotating banner.

*For simplicity I will stick with the drop down menu as an example (I assume that they are both going to be solved by targeting the correct path)*

Selenium builder generates a JSON file. I think adjusting this file could be the answer to my problems, but I am struggling to work out what adjustments I can make to target the link I am after.

**the HTML I am targeting**

```
<div id="locale-switcher" style="display: none"> 
    <li class="language-switcher OneLinkNoTx"> 
         <a href="#language-options">Select language</a> 
         <ul id="language-options"> 
             <li><a class="modal-link" href="#currency-change" rel="/uk/store/" onclick="confirmStoreSwitch(this.rel);">English</a></li> 
             <li><a class="modal-link" href="#currency-change" rel="/other/store/" onclick="confirmStoreSwitch(this.rel);">Other</a></li> 
         </ul> 
    </li> 
</div>
```

**the generated json file**

```
{
  "type": "script",
  "seleniumVersion": "2",
  "formatVersion": 2,
  "steps": [
    {
      "type": "get",
      "url": "http://www.mySite.co.uk/uk/store/"
    },
{
  "type": "clickElement",
  "locator": {
    "type": "link text",
    "value": "English"
  }
}
  ],
  "data": {
    "configs": {},
    "source": "none"
  },
  "inputs": []
}
```

The program also suggests alternative to target a desired element, in this case:

**"type": "clickElement" suggested alt1:**

```
  "locator": {
    "type": "css selector",
    "value": "a.modal-link"
  }
```

**"type": "clickElement" suggested alt2:**

```
  "locator": {
    "type": "xpath",
    "value": "//ul[@id='language-options']//a[.='English']"
  }
```

**"type": "clickElement" suggested alt3**

```
 "locator": {
    "type": "xpath",
    "value": "//div[1]/header/nav/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]/a"
 }
```

But non of these suggestions are working. How can I target the required element?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it. The answer was not adjusting the JSON file as it seems that even if you pass valid JSON it may not be read by selenium builder.

Ultimately the answer was getting the correct xpath and not trying to click the element but verify its there, store it and retrieve it.

To get an xpath (using firebug)
Navigate to the link you are targeting
Right click and select "inspect element with firebug"
Right click on the element(or text) itself and select copy xpath

Selenium builder will also provide you with the xpath just by clicking on the link but it will set the command **clickElementAttribute** you will need to change this.

The order I took to target a drop down menu item in selenium builder is listed below:

**get** [www.myHomePage.com]

**verifyTextPresent** [visible menu link]

**storeElementAttribute** *locator* [xpath to hidden item], *attribute name* href, *variable* link

**verifyElementAttribute** *locator* [xpath to hidden item], *attribute name* href, *variable* ${link}

**get** ${link}

**waitForCurrentUrl** [the/url/you/are/targeting]

Please note link and ${link} are variables and should be written as they are written above. You could use the same technique for a rotating banner, alternatively you could use the command **waitForTextPresent**  the **clickElementAttribute**